Why is my projectile moving in the wrong direction?
I want my projectile to go in the direction the player is facing.
The controller code is this:
GameOject obj = Instantiate(projectile, transform.rotation,bulletParent.transform.parent);
obj.AddComponent<projectilecontroller>();
obj.GetComponent<projectilecontroller>().speed = weapon.velocity;
obj.GetComponent<projectilecontroller>().angle = transform.rotation;
obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass = weapon.projectileMass; 

And my projectile controller is:
rb.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(rb.velocity.x,rb.velocity.y,speed));

Both are encased in a class and all of the things don't return null.
The hierarchy is:
weapon
camera
bulletParent
and I have a prefab for the bullet that has a rigid body
The weapon consists of the weapon controller and inside the script there is a weapon thing:
[createassetmenu(menuName="weapon")]
class weapon: scriptibleobject{
     public float velocity,projectilemass;
}

When I run it however, the projectile seems to be about 45 degrees more than the weapon.
Thanks
P.S I'm new at asking questions, please tell me if I've missed any important info

Is the "controller code" attached to the player?  Specifically, does transform.rotation refer to the players rotation?  If so, the projectile is already pointed forward.

Not enough code or directions on how to setup the scene hierarchy to reproduce the problem. Please edit the question to include a [mre].

Might I ask why you dont use AddForce ?
Im by no means an expert on unity, but i distinctly remember that one usually shouldt manipulate/replace the velocity directly, and instead use AddForce. Again im not that deep in unity but that just comes to my mind

It's very difficult to tell how your logic is working exactly because you've removed the code from its context. For example, does the projectile code you showed us run in the Update() method? I don't know.
Regardless, I think I can help you out.
First of all, you should totally update a RigidBody's velocity by using the appropriate methods provided by the class. Also, note that Transform.TransformDirection "Transforms direction from local space to world space." according to the docs here. I don't think this is the vector you want to be setting your velocity to.
Here is what I suggest. Add a Vector3 called direction to your projectilecontroller. Then in your player controller, where you instantiate your projectile, pass it the player's transform.forward vector. Something like so:
obj.GetComponent<projectilecontroller>().direction = transform.forward;

Then in the projectile's FixedUpdate() method:
rb.AddForce(direction * speed, ForceMode.VelocityChange)

This method already accounts for the Time.fixedDeltaTime so do NOT include this as a factor in the force argument. You can also choose a different ForceMode if you want to ignore mass or not, or apply an acceleration rather. VelocityChange achieves what your code tried to: setting the velocity directly without considering the Rigidbody's mass. Docs for the Rigidbody.AddForce() method are here.
Should you also want the projectile to face the direction it's moving in, add this to an update loop on your projectile:
transform.forward = direction;

Assuming the front of the projectile is pointing in the positive z direction. You can always just change the aforementioned transform accordingly. Otherwise look into using Transform.LookAt().
I think that should solve the problem. let me know please!
Now for a handy tip:
You show us the following code of yours:
GameOject obj = Instantiate(projectile, transform.rotation,bulletParent.transform.parent);
obj.AddComponent<projectilecontroller>();
obj.GetComponent<projectilecontroller>().speed = weapon.velocity;
obj.GetComponent<projectilecontroller>().angle = transform.rotation;
obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass = weapon.projectileMass; 

which is extremely inefficient. Calling GetComponent() is no light task and is unnecessary to do this many times because you are accessing the exact same component each time. You should cache the component in a variable, do what work you need to it, then be done. In fact, since you are adding the component, you don't even need to call GetComponent() at all. So the above code can be refactored to:
var obj = Instantiate(projectile, transform.rotation,bulletParent.transform.parent);
var projectile = obj.AddComponent<projectilecontroller>();
projectile.speed = weapon.velocity;
projectile.angle = transform.rotation;
projectile.mass = weapon.projectileMass; 

which also just looks neater and more concise. It's also far more performant.
